# android exception of drawing buttons with background of sharp corners

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to draw 3 buttons with white corners like that .sorry I can't post images...

```
 normal:          button1  |  button2  |  button3  [sharp] corners around them
 in fact:         ===============================  white corner and all white in it
```

however,in Android 4.4 the background of these buttons is totally white and I can't see the text of buttons ,I start and finish this activity 10 times and 2 of 10 are normal

sorry again for no image..

button.xml

```
<!-- 3 Buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/corners_bg_chartbuttons"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonDaily"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

        .......................................

</LinearLayout>
```

corners_bg_chartbuttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />  
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@android:color/white" />  
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="2dp"      
    android:topRightRadius="2dp"       
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"      
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"/>
```

Comment: android:textColor="@android:color/black" for text

Comment: @RemeesMSyde it did't work ,the background also white not transparant